# Accessing the excel link sources method in javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I am attempting to use javascript to automate some things in excel.  So far I have got it to open the appropriate workbooks as an activeX object.  I am now trying to check the links and update them is needed.  I cannot figure out how to access the linksources method of the workbooks.

So far I have tried:

```
wb.LinkSources(1)
wb.LinkSources[1]
wb.[LinkSources]
wb.[LinkSources[1]]
```

and many other similar variations, resulting in values of "function expected", "Expected identifier", or "undefined"

I'm fairly new to js, but I feel as though I have tried about all the variations on that syntax I can think of.  Thanks for any help!

My complete function is:

```
function open_files(A, B, C) 
{ 
 var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
 excel.visible=true;
 excel.DisplayAlerts = false

 var wbA = excel.Workbooks.Open(document.getElementById(A).value);
 var wbB = excel.Workbooks.Open(document.getElementById(B).value);
 var wbC = excel.Workbooks.Open(document.getElementById(C).value);

 excel.EnableEvents = false
 excel.ScreenUpdating = false
 excel.Calculation = -4135 //xlCalculationManual enumeration

 var wb_collection = [wbA, wbB, wbC];
 for (var wb in wb_collection)
 {
  var x = wb_collection[wb].LinkSources(1)
  for (var link in wb_collection[wb].LinkSources(1))
  {
/*

   if (wb_collection[wb].LinkSources(1)(link) = wbA.Fullname //|| wb_collection [wb].LinkSources(1)(link) = wbB.Fullname || wb_collection[wb].LinkSources(1)(link) = wbC.FullName);
   {
    blah blah code code
   }
*/
  }
 }
```